# Plot basic graph with no borders, titles, etc

Tags: r, plot, raster

I want to make a plot which takes up the entire space; no borders, no scale bars, etc.

I tried:

```
sp.predict <- predict(tstack, sp.tree4, 
   n.trees=sp.tree4$gbm.call$best.trees, 
   type = "response")    
plot(sp.predict)
```

Which gives me the plot fine but has a border, blank space where the titles should go, etc. How can I get the plot to take up the entire space?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It's a pretty large rasterstack, I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `par(mar=rep(0,4))`, as shown in this example from `?plot.raster`:

```
 require(grDevices)
 r <- as.raster(c(0.5, 1, 0.5))
 ## ... snip
 # fill page
 op <- par(mar=rep(0, 4))
 plot(r, asp=NA)
 par(op)
```

You may also want to add `legend=FALSE` ...

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks. This seems to have almost got there, but not quite. The scale seems to have shifted a bit off and there's still the bar on the side.

Original: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hqr0d1&s=8#.VYi1fEarGl4

Updated: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10ieaub&s=8#.VYi2U0arGl4

Comment: This will be easier with a reproducible example, or at least with the output of `str(sp.predict)` ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270107/r-get-a-specific-band-of-a-rasterlayer may provide a reproducible example.  Have you tried adding `legend=FALSE` ?

Comment: legend = FALSE removed the legend but the plot still isn't taking up the space where the legend was. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help, almost there!

Comment: I have to admit I'm stumped now.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it's closer than before at least!